# On my school's webpage, we want to keep the profession list up to date automatically. How do I link LinkedIn?

Tags: html, css-selectors

On my school's webpage, we want to keep the profession list up to date automatically. How do I link LinkedIn so that the page updates when LinkedIn changes?

I would like to link Linkedin to our university's website. In doing so, it will keep us from constantly having to update the page

~Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply divide and conquer to this issue.

First attack the problem of gathering information from LinkedIn,

You can start here https://www.linkedin.com/developers and take a look at the [API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/).

Also you have [LinkedIn badges](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-linkedin-badge-your-website-brynne-tillman/), but it doesn't look exactly like something you are looking for.